# How to find all maximal chains and antichains in a finite bounded lattice

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, lattice-orders

Is there a (possibly efficient) algorithm to find all maximal chains and antichains in a finite bounded lattice?

Comment: Have you tried something like max-flow/min-cut? Such as Ford-Fulkerson or something?